# How do I set up a test environment in a sub-folder?

Tags: migration, testing, customization, staging

I have my first-ever, live client who needs a website completely re-done.  We're leaning towards setting up a premium WordPress theme. I've done this for close friends and family members before (set up the domain name, hosting, install [WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) all that), but this is the first time that I've ever done this for a "real", professional client who already has their own website and hosting.

But I'm not sure where to begin! So I have a few questions:

- I've heard that the best way to set up a WordPress site for a client is to set up the site in its own sub-folder on my own hosting. Then, once everything is approved and good to go copy the client's files and database files and transfer them to the client's hosting server. I've never done anything like this before. How do I do this properly? And once they're happy, how do I transfer the site from my test environment to their outside hosting?
- How do you guys normally charge for this type of job? By the hour? A certain amount per job?
- Any tips for making sure my first ever WordPress client project goes smoothly?

I realize that my questions are very rookie. But my biggest concern is setting up the test environment, then transferring it over to the client in a smooth, seamless way. I'm very excited, but I don't want to screw this up!

Comment: I am close voting the question as I don't see that there can be any authoritative answer here, only opinions. What is the best environment/development practice depends on your communication skills and budget. It varies from client to client and project to project. Good development practice will take longer to set up (but hopefully you will get a working site in the end) hacking is easy to start but problems might badly derail you. Each developer need to find his own comfort zone and develop his own workflow that works good for him

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on your first client. I'm glad you are looking around to make sure that you start off on the right foot. Like anything that you start in life, your experience will increase over time and the more you practice.

However, we live in a digital age and popular open-source platforms such as WordPress have great tutorials and communities to answer just about every question.

These are some good, but also heavy questions, I want to keep them brief and too the point with you:

> *I've heard that the best way to set up a WordPress site for a client is to set up the site in its own sub-folder on my own hosting. Then, once everything is approved and good to go copy the client's files and database files and transfer them to the client's hosting server. I've never done anything like this before. How do I do this properly?*

Workflows vary depending on how big or small your organization is. For individuals, your resources may be limited and they are simple; corporations would usually have a bigger team of poeple with assigned roles and protocols to follow.

Since you, the developer, have been contracted to rebuild a new website for your clients. It's definitely an ideal way to build the new WordPress site on your own hosting (`example.com/client/name`) to have full control and hide your client's new website from being.

[Check out this helpful guide](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/) and also look at our [migration](/questions/tagged/migration) related Q&A which people have already posted some step-by-step guides.

> How do you guys normally charge for this type of job? By the hour? A certain amount per job?

This will vary per developer because there are a lot of variable to factor in and each scenario is unique. Start off by determining your worth based on your level of experience in web development, the average pricing around your area, and your overall work ethic.

Start at a comfortable price, then work your way up as you become more experienced over time.

> Any tips for making sure my first ever WordPress client project goes smoothly?

While everyone wants every web project to *go smoothly*, you're guaranteed to run to some issues from time to time. It's part of the learning experience. However, it's more important to be able to fix those issues to improve your skills.

I can guarantee you will run into common issues, but when you learn how to rectify them, you'll know how to prevent them in the future.

Comment: One of the mistakes you see in questions here is "I developed on local host, moved to client and it fails" development should be done in as close as possible to the deployment server environment so developing on your own server is not a very good option (how will you find e-mail is not configured on the server? lack of the rewrite module etc). Doing subdirectory is an awful idea by itself as the final site is unlikely to be in a subdirectory. Development is probably best done on a client's server to which he can just switch DNS from the current one.

Answer (score 0):

For clients website, after you have setup everything, you could upload to your hosting or client's one. But, if you put on client, that would be good if you and the clients have trust relationship.

- Make sure when you move local to live server not to be broken. Firstly, create a subdomain to show your clients or you could even install in subfolder.When everything is ready, move it to clients server without breaking. It is your potential.
- How much you should charge is depending on your time consuming. But, not first time should be flexible. not too much lower and not too much higher. Some clients give the project price 1/4 or 1/3. As soon as you get first payment, you have to hit the project and show the project demo to be able to check how the project is going from the client side. And then, take second or third payment like that.
- Use project management software like [trello](http://trello.com). So, both you could work well on it without missing anything.
- Take at least 1 days to check your project before, it is online.

Frankly to say, there are some other tips and tricks that need to know. So, read a little bit online. Have a good luck with your clients.

Answer (score 0):

### Setup

Something easy and convenient for you to start:

- Buy a cheap domain name like acme.gdn (client is Acme Inc.)
- And a month or two on some cheap but rather good hosting with Cpanel and Fantastico installer
- Install wordpress on it using Fantastico
- Install plugin [BackWPup](https://wordpress.org/plugins/backwpup/)
- Setup automatic daily or semi-daily backup with Dropbox as a destination
- Work on the website ... Do your stuff ... Review until approved
- Remove you backup jobs or replace theme with client credentials
- Install [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) and use it to do the migration to the client server, I won't go through the process as it's easy and well documented

### How much to charge

As much as you are worth, more or less, do not race to the bottom.

### Tips

- Don't overdo it or you'll end up working on the project for ages
- Impress the client with some nice suggestions
- and some freebies that won't take much time
- Make sure site is fast
- Ask a friend with more experience to review the website